# PHP: Find one or more enclosed area in a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

There is (10x10) two-dimensional array (matrix) of zeros and ones. Need algorithm (the implementation) that determines whether in this array closed path of ones, that surround the zeros. The output is true or false.

For example:

```
function findEnclosedArea($array) {
    // check $array ???

    return true/false;
}
```

The figure below illustrates outputs:

[image: Red is false, green is true return]

- If the array contains only 0, the return value is true.
- If the array contains only 1, the return value is false.
- If there are (containing one or more 0s) "enclosed areas" surrounded by ones, the return value is false.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: No code. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you could try to use floodfill. Start on any 0 element, than if by the end there are any 0 elements it hasn't reached, you know those are probably enclosed, or the element you started from was enclosed. Either way in that case you can return false, otherwise return true.

Comment: Floodfill. Good idea! I'll try. Thanx.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help! It has been solved. The Floodfill algorithm works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help! This is the right solution:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2cb5c98f2d58079024e0890a37845489dd6e2697

```
<?php
// DEFINE DIMENSIONS
define("ROWS", 10);
define("COLUMNS", 10);

/**
 * checkZeros
 * Find zero values in the two-dimensional array, 
 * If found then return an array else return bool false
 * @param Array $array An two-dimensional array with 0 or 1
 * @return indexed Array (x, y) or Bool false
 */
function checkZeros($array) {
    for($x = 0; $x < ROWS; $x++) {
        for($y = 0; $y < COLUMNS; $y++) {
            if($array[$x][$y] === 0) {
                return array($x, $y);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * floodFillWithTwos (recursive!)
 * Flood fill 0s with 2s in the two-dimensional array 
 * Start with x, y position and steps north-east-south-west direction
 * @param Array $array An two-dimensional array with 0s or 1s or 2s
 * @param Array $start An indexed array with 2 values (x, y start positions) for find
 * @return Bool true/false
 */
function floodFillWithTwos($array, $start = false) {
    if(!$start || !is_array($start) || count($start) != 2) {
        return $array;
    }
    $x = (int)$start[0]; $y = (int)$start[1];
    if ($x < 0 || $x >= ROWS || $y < 0 || $y >= COLUMNS || $array[$x][$y] != 0) {
        return $array;
    }
    // Filling value: 2
    $array[$x][$y] = 2;
    
    // Recursive for north, east, south and west
    $array = floodFillWithTwos($array, array($x + 1, $y));
    $array = floodFillWithTwos($array, array($x - 1, $y));
    $array = floodFillWithTwos($array, array($x, $y + 1));
    $array = floodFillWithTwos($array, array($x, $y - 1));   
    
    return $array;
}

/**
 * findEnclosedArea
 * Find the enclosed area in a two-dimensional array, 
 * If found then return false else return true
 * @param Array $array An two-dimensional array with 0 or 1
 * @return Bool true or false
 */
function findEnclosedArea($array) {
    $x = checkZeros($array);
    // If not found 0s (only 1s or 2s)
    if($x === false) {
      return false;
    }
    // Flood fill :: 0s --> 2s
    $array = floodFillWithTwos($array, $x);
    $x = checkZeros($array);
    if($x === false) {
      // If not found zeros
      return true;
    }
    // If found zeros
    return false;
}

// EXAMPLE ARRAYS

$example_1 = array(
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
    array(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
);

$example_2 = array(
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
    array(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
);

$example_3 = array(
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    array(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
);

$example_4 = array(
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
);

$example_5 = array(
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
);

$example_6 = array(
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
);


// Enclosed: false / Not-enclosed: true
var_dump(findEnclosedArea($example_1));
var_dump(findEnclosedArea($example_2));
var_dump(findEnclosedArea($example_3));
var_dump(findEnclosedArea($example_4));
var_dump(findEnclosedArea($example_5));
var_dump(findEnclosedArea($example_6));
```